# Compare two values from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking to compare the input of two input fields. Before that two Arrays have been created, so when the index of the array 'lenghtOfBoat' is equal or higher than the index of the array 'HKboat', it should output a text string saying something specific.

This is my current code: (I'm still new to JS, but trying my best)

```
var lenghtOfBoat = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var inputBoatLenght = document.getElementById("boatLenght");

var statusLength = inputBoatLenght.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if(lenghtOfBoat.indexOf(+this.value) > -1){
    console.log(this.value);
  }else{
    console.log(this.value);
  }
  return this.value
})


var HKboat = [4.10, 5.15, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var inputBoatHK = document.getElementById("boatHK");

var statusHK = inputBoatHK.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if(HKboat.indexOf(+this.value) > -1){
    console.log(this.value);
  }else{
    console.log(this.value);
  }
  return this.value
})


if(statusLength <= statusHK) {
    console.log("Yipsi");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Systematic typo"? | And what's the problem with your current code?

Comment: What are you comparing there are not the values, but EventListener objects.

Comment: The issues is that I'm not shown Yipsi in my console when the two input fields are equal.

Answer (score 0):

And something like this? I don't know if it works but maybe it helps.

```
var lenghtOfBoat = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var inputBoatLenght = document.getElementById("boatLenght");

inputBoatLenght.addEventListener("change", function() {
  //Gather info and send check
  checkValues(this.value, inputBoatHK.value);
})


var HKboat = [4.10, 5.15, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var inputBoatHK = document.getElementById("boatHK");

inputBoatHK.addEventListener("change", function() {
  //Gather info and send check
  checkValues(inputBoatLenght.value, this.value);
})

function checkValues (statusLength, statusHK) {
  if(statusLength <= statusHK) {
    console.log("Yipsi");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but it's not the actual number that is given as an input that should be compared. Rather it should be the index number in the array of the input number. Ex.

If input of 'boatLenght' is 6 and input of 'boatHK' is 4.10 the console shouldn't log anything.

However, is the 'boatLenght' 6 and the 'boatHK' is 6 (or 7, 8, or 9) the console should log Yipsi.

So it's the position in the array of each input that should be compared. So if the index number of 'boatLenght' is 6, the console should only log if the input of 'boatHK' is equal or more than the index of 'boatLenght'.

Comment: My code it's almost what you need, change the values passed as arguments to "checkValues" and you'll have it.